# Get and set not working properly

Tags: c#, xna

> ```
> public Vector2 Get()
> {
>     return var2;
> }
>
> public void Set(Vector2 var1)
> {
>     var2 = var1;
> }
> ```
>
> For some reason if call Get(), var2 is (0, 0)... even though both var 1 X and Y are greater than 0...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, Vector2 (and var2) is structure?

Comment: complete your post with other code (assignment and declaration of class), thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you doing this with a Property?

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax for a property in C# is:

```
public <TYPE_NAME> <PROPERTY_NAME>
{
    get
    {
        return <LOGIC HERE>;
    }
    set
    {
        //value is whatever the property is set to in the calling code
        <local_var, or whatever> = value;
    }
}
```

Please look stuff like this up [on Google](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)  first.

Comment: That still does not explain why the code isn't working. Just because you *can* use properties does not mean you *have* to.

Comment: Unfortunately with the amount of information given we had to guess at what the original question meant.  My best guess was that he wanted to know how to use properties...